# jQuery modal stack with ajax forms

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function that opens a url inside a modal and there can be multiple modals on the page. In one such example the user would open up a modal from another modal say to edit some content that is currently being show in the first modal.

The problem is when the form inside the second modal is submitted (using ajax) is how to refresh the first modal. I would need to know two things which modal to refresh and what content to use to refresh the modal with.

Has anyone ever done anything like this before? Has some ideas?

The only idea I could come up with was to record the indexes and urls each time a user clicks an ajax modal link and store them in an array and then when the form submits check if the parent modal of the form index matches one of the arrays and then use the values to refresh the correct modal with the url that is also stored inside the array. But this is very long-winded and quite sloppy and the results are unpredictable.

Anyone got any other/better solutions?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you want to open a new modal from the current modal and, upon finishing that child modal, reload the OLD modal with the updated contents modified by the child one. Ooooooof!

A piece of your code would help. But here it goes (I have done that b-4-2):

create an empty div on the current modal(could be standard with your modal div ... with display:none and id='dataExchange' for example).

Drop the modified stuff from the child modal into that dataExchange div.

Upon completion of the child modal, load the appropriate stuff from the dataExchange div into the oldContent (reloaded with the $('#'+your-modal-id).html(unescape(oldContent))) keep it hidden while updating it and fade it back out; slide it back out; etc.

Am I in the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use

`ajaxModalInstance.find('.uiModal').attr('data-url', clickedLink.attr('href'));`

to pass the modal url as HTML5 data that I can then use to refresh all modals on the page using the data attribute of the modal

Answer (score -1):

I do that a lot! The secret is to keep the old modal content in a variable. Very simple:

```
var oldContent=''; //outside your loop or modal procedures
.. onClick="oldContent=escape($('#'+your-modal-id).html()); "

.. on process finished:
if (oldContent != '') $('#'+your-modal-id).html(unescape(oldContent));
```

Have fun!

Comment: That wouldn't work as the oldContent would be OLD and not the reloaded content with the amends that have been made in the second modal.

Comment: Not to mention that oldContent would be get overwritten every time a user clicked a modal button! Hence why I mentioned looping an array.

Comment: 30 years ago, when I had my Structured System Analisys classes, my teacher insisted that every user is going to ask you for a circle but you will ALWAYS deliver a square. Moral: communication ...